# Validation without objects using Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

good evening.

I'm having trouble while trying to validate a variable using `Joi`. I've read this page [link](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md)

Joi usually validates object through schemas, however, the page I mentioned show that Joi also supports a more "direct" approach to validation. In my case, I'm trying just to validate a variable.

I'm trying the following:

```
const {error, value} = Joi.number().validate("SAMPLE TEXT");
```

It's not precisely what I'm trying to do (I'd change "SAMPLE TEXT" for a variable), but It's a good example to show my problem.

What I'd expect from this code is that an error is thrown (because validation should fail), meaning that ** error should not be null or undefined **, however, when trying:

```
console.log(`Error: ${error}`};
```

I get:

> Error: undefined

Can anyone help me?

[]

Answer (score 0):

> Check your package is installed perfectly. I did not find any issue in your code. I have run it properly.

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi'); check this line also
```

[image: Here is the prove]

Comment: Hello, MD Rana Hossain. Unfortunately the package is correctly installed. The only difference between your code and mine is that I was using `require("joi")` but after I changed to `require(@hapi/joi)` nothing changed. I use validations on other functions and it works pretty nice. Really confused about this issue. Thanks

Comment: can you vote for me, please? It's inspired me for helping the people.

Comment: Sorry Md Rana Hossain.

I really appreciate your help, but unfortunately I can't vote up due to my reputation being below 15.